# Prevent IdP users from saving to Keycloak local storage at login

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api, keycloak-connect

I want to prevent IdP users from being saved to the Keycloak local storage when they login.
Is there some sort of switch in the admin console that prevents IdP users from being saved to the Keycloak local storage?
Or how can I achieve this programmatically?